# Problema com o tipo de encode que recebo de uma bd sybase

Tags: php, odbc, sybase

Boas, estou a receber valores de uma base de dados sybase através do odbc em php.

Acontece que quando imprimo caracteres especiais ,como ô ou ç, são imprimidos '??' em vez destes.

Ja tentei usar o iconv(), utf8 decode()/encode(),tenho incluido no codigo"" e já tentei usar a class ForceUTF-8 para converter os valores mas nada resulta.

Para tentar descobrir o tipo de encode dos dados que recebia utilizei a função mb_detect_encoding() mas ela retorna-me vazio em todos os resultados com caracteres especiais.

Alguem tem solução ou ideia do que se possa estar a passar? 
(Não posso mudar directamente o tipo de encode da base de dados)

Código:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$servidorodbc=file('odbc.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$dsn=$servidorodbc['0'];
$user=$servidorodbc['1'];
$pwd=$servidorodbc['2'];


if($pwd="''"){
  $pwd="";
};
$db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);




$query = odbc_exec($db, 'Select * from GP_Vw_Valores_Pagos where Ano=2019 and Codigo=18990 order by CD');


use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;

echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dération Camerounaise de Football\n");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-m-12 col-l-12 col-xl-12">
                                            <table id="tabela" class="table" ;>

                                                <tr>

                                                    <th scope="col">Descrição</th> 

                                                </tr>

                                                <?php while ( $row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <tr style="text-align: right;">

                                                        <td class="center" style="text-align;"><?=  $row['Descricao']?></td>


                                                    </tr>

                                                <?php }?>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-2 col-l-2 col-xl-2">
                                            <form method="post">
                                                <input type="submit" name="grafico" class="btn btn-success" value = "Grafico">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-2 col-l-2 col-xl-2"></div>
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-2 col-l-2 col-xl-2"></div>
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-4 col-l-2 col-xl-2"></div>
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-2 col-l-2 col-xl-2">
                                            <form action="../../app/excel.php" method="post">
                                                <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn excel" value = "Exportar para excel">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-m-2 col-l-2 col-xl-2"><a class="btn buttonstyle mr-5" target="_blank" href="../../app/imprimePA.php">Imprimir</a></div>
                                    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui nesse momento `$db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);` que está a solução, você precisa definir que a conexão seja feita em UTF-8 assim:

```
<?php
    $dsn.="CharacterSet => UTF-8";
    $db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);
?>
```

Mas para isso, certifique-se que o conteúdo da variável `$dsn` tenha `;` no final, para não ocorrão outros erros.